# Transforming characters in Python

Tags: python

```
mir = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q',  'r', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y']

keq = ['.', 'c', 'z', 's', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'b', 'v', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 'u', 'x', ''\'', 'y']
```

I want to know if any of the characters in `keq` are pressed in `raw_input('write text: ')`
 to transform them in characters that are shown in `mir`

Can someone help me do this... If you can write all the code it will help me so much

Comment: Sure there are lots of people here who can write that code for you, but what is the reason that someone should do that?

Comment: I want to compare those characters... if I didnt have a reason I wouldnt post it here man :S

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like a homework assignment you're trying to get someone to do. If it isn't, please elaborate.

Comment: When a question contains the phrase, "If you can write all the code it will help me so much", people naturally get suspicious. Personally, I'd be more than willing to give you some tips, but having someone write all the code for you isn't how you advance past the beginner stage.

Comment: @altin: Sure we want to help you. But we want you to at least try it out. If you fail, we will tell you where you were wrong. But coming here and saying: `if you can write all the code` doesn't work. Think about it, you won't learn.

Comment: @altin: I get the feeling you are taking some sort of programming course, and this is homework. Programming requires a deep understanding. You will not pass this course if you get somebody else to answer your homework for you. You either understand how to write it, or fail.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** You could built a translation table for characters using the [`maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.maketrans) and [`translate` methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), e.g.

```
>>> import string
>>> tb = string.maketrans('abc', '123')
>>> 'cyan banana'.translate(tb)
'3y1n 21n1n1'
```

**2.** You could concatenate all strings in an array using the [`''.join` method](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), e.g.

```
>>> arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> ''.join(arr)
'abc'
```

These should be enough to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
mir = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y']
keq = ['.', 'c', 'z', 's', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'i', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'b', 'v', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 't', 'u', 'x', '\\', 'y']
trans = dict(zip(mir,keq))

myStr = raw_input()
print ''.join([trans.has_key(ch) and trans[ch] or ch for ch in myStr])
```

Comment: +1 nice use of dict,zip. You can also use get and generator expr. `print ''.join(trans.get(ch, ch) for ch in myStr)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary for the transformation ...

```
{
 'a' : '.',
 'b' : 'c',
  ...
```

then use `map` to walk through your input, replacing keys with values.